# Unable to connect redis pod in kubernetes Unable to connect to redis-service/<unresolved>:6379

Tags: java, kubernetes, redis

I have a requirement where my java app is connecting with redis server

This is my redis config file

```
   apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: redis-config
    data:
      SPRING_REDIS_HOST: redis-service    # Replace with your Redis service name
      SPRING_REDIS_PORT: '6379'              # Redis default port

This is my secret file 

   

     apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret  # For a secret file, the kind should be "Secret"
    metadata:
      name: redis-secret  # This is a user-defined name for the Secret
    type: Opaque  # Default type for a secret file
    data:
      SPRING_REDIS_PASSWORD: cmVkaXNwYXNzd29yZA==  # The value here should be converted to base64

this is my redis deployment and service 

    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    name: redis
    component: cache
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis
        component: cache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args: ["--requirepass", "$(REDIS_PASS)"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
        env:
        - name: MASTER
          value: "true"
        - name: REDIS_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: redis-secret
              key: SPRING_REDIS_PASSWORD
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379  # Default Redis port
      targetPort: 6379  # Target port on the pods
```

this is my java application pod where i am passing the env variables

```
   apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment  # Deployment file kind should be "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: cartsmicroservice-deployment
  labels:
    app: cartsmicroservice
spec:
  replicas: 1  # How many pods you want to create
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cartsmicroservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cartsmicroservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cartsmicroservice
        image: faizannaeem1994/cartsmicroservice:latest  # Image name; using official mongo image with tag 7.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8001 
        env:
        - name: SPRING_REDIS_HOST  # Environment variables used in the code
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: redis-config  # Secret file metadata name
              key: SPRING_REDIS_HOST  # Defined in secret file
        - name: SPRING_REDIS_PORT  # Environment variables used in the code
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: redis-config  # Secret file metadata name
              key: SPRING_REDIS_PORT  # Defined in secret file
        - name: SPRING_REDIS_PASSWORD  # Environment variables used in the code
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: redis-secret  # Secret file metadata name
              key: SPRING_REDIS_PASSWORD  # Defined in secret file
---
# Here we describe service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service  # It should be "Service"
metadata:
  name: cartsmicroservice-service  # It can be anything (remember in config file we use this service name)
spec:
  type: NodePort  # Make it an external service so we can access it
  selector:
    app: cartsmicroservice  # It should match the name of the pods so service knows for which pods it should forward the request
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8001  # It can be anything (better to make it the same as container port)
      targetPort: 8001  # It should be the same as the container port
      nodePort: 30300  # Range is from 30000 to 32767
```

Unable to connect to redis-service/ unresolved :6379

I have checked the logs of the redis service it is running , but when i deploy the java app it gives me error which i am not getting

Comment: Is your application using Spring Boot version 3 perchance?  That renamed the Spring Data Redis configuration properties, and you would need to change the `env: [{ name: }]` values to `SPRING_DATA_REDIS_HOST` and `SPRING_DATA_REDIS_PORT`.